# Width and height is 0 when using SpriteVisualElement but is correct size when using Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have some code that when I use a Sprite the width and height values ares set when using addChild but when using a SpriteVisualElement the width and height are 0.

```
        var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        // ...
        sprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        sprite.transform.matrix = target.transform.matrix;
        sprite.addChild(bitmap); // width and height 250x65

        var spritevisualElement:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();

        // ...
        spriteVisualElement.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        spriteVisualElement.transform.matrix = target.transform.matrix;
        spriteVisualElement.addChild(bitmap); // spriteVisualElement width and height 0x0
```

What is going on? Can I make SpriteVisualElement work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bounds for the actual size (btw `SpriteVisualElement` uses bounds as well when measures itself in the `measure` method, but by some reasons `measure` isn't called by flex automatically and there isn't way (I can't find it) to call it manually):

```
var bounds:Rectangle = container.getBounds(container);
trace("size:", bounds.right, bounds.bottom); //<-- clip the container by the rectangle with origin at (0, 0)
trace("size:", bounds.width, bounds.height); //<-- full with/height
```

output:

```
size: 100 100
size: 100 100
```